# encode url in java and javascript yielding different results

Tags: javascript, java

I have a requirement to generate the url and use it as a sitemap.
But, if the url is different on frontend and backend, then there's a redirection will happen to the url the front-end uses, due to which google seo ranking is going low. So i need to generate same result in backend and frontend for both the results.

```
JAVA CODE
@Test
    public void testUrl() {
        String s = "tata, abcd & xyz - 1/2kg ()";
        String encode = URLEncoder.encode(s, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(encode);
    }
RESULT: tata%2C+abcd+%26+xyz+-+1%2F2kg+%28%29

=====
JS CODE
encodeURIComponent("tata, abcd & xyz - 1/2kg ()");
RESULT: tata%2C%20abcd%20%26%20xyz%20-%201%2F2kg%20()
```

Can you please help me yield same result for both.
I am more in favor of '+' sign instead of %20

Comment: Both are valid. Different libraries can have different implementations. It doesn't really matter in practice.

Comment: I know both are valid, but i need same results across both else, my application will redirect and cause issues in google seo

Comment: Then find a JS library that uses `+` or allows you to configure it. If this question is a request for a library, I'll have to vote to close as such.

Comment: @Jorn, I believe they're asking how to make the values equivalent; since the _Java_ implementation is slightly different.

Comment: You're using two different things. `URLEncoder` is for applying `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding of keys and values, while `encodeURIComponent` is for encoding URI components. Use the right tool for the job, don't mix two different things just because they (seem to) _share_ similar encodings.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, a URL is a URI.

Comment: There are some conversion examples in the _Mozilla_ documentation; _https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent_.

Comment: @Reilas My point is that `URLEncoder` **does not encode URI/URL components**, it encodes string so they are valid keys or values for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (the basic encoded form of a HTML form), so it is not the equivalent of `encodeURIComponent`, which is for encoding path parts of a URI/URL.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I must be misunderstanding.  Are they not interchangeable?  Even the _Mozilla_ documentation is providing examples.

Comment: @Reilas They use the same percent-encoding scheme, so they will seem to be interchangeable, until they are not... To be clear, the (IIRC only) difference is how spaces are encoded with a `+` instead of %20, because `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is based on an older version of URI encoding.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, possibly it depends on the browser.  Chrome decodes it correctly, I'm not sure about the others.

Answer (score 0):

As a note, the *encodeURIComponent* method didn't encode the parentheses, either.

Just use the *[String.replaceAll](https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/#sec-string.prototype.replaceall)* method.

```js
var string = encodeURIComponent("tata, abcd & xyz - 1/2kg ()")
string = string.replaceAll('%20', '+')

console.log(string)
```

If you wanted to escape the parentheses, just use the same method.

```js
var string = encodeURIComponent("tata, abcd & xyz - 1/2kg ()")
string = string.replaceAll('%20', '+')
string = string.replaceAll('(', '%28')
string = string.replaceAll(')', '%29')

console.log(string)
```

And, when you decode the value, make sure to replace the *+* signs prior to the *decodeURIComponent* call.

```js
var string = encodeURIComponent("tata, abcd & xyz - 1/2kg ()")
string = string.replaceAll('%20', '+')
string = string.replaceAll('(', '%28')
string = string.replaceAll(')', '%29')

console.log(string)

string = string.replaceAll('+', ' ')
string = decodeURIComponent(string)

console.log(string)
```